# Unity's obi cloth asset isn't working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloth-simulation

I was trying out the obi cloth asset and I ran into a problem, as shown in the photo I'm trying to make a cape for my character (I'm using the third person controller asset if that will help in anyway) so I tried out the obi cloth component everything was working fine until I tried to move around as you can see the cape isn't smoothly following the mesh (the cape is skinned to the armature).

[A photo from the project to demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CLuj.png)

I thought it might be a problem within the mesh itself but when I remove the cloth component it's working fine, I also thought that might be a problem in the asset where you can't move around because in all the tutorials that I was saw on the internet they were using a static character with an animator on it but I found this video where it seems to be working fine: [Obi Cloth 3 for Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgMuGRCnqXw&list=PLnCR8_XCOgrb3S5UsDor6fAHdzlzdwEr4)

What might be causing that problem how could I fix it? If not, is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: possibly animation related, as animations dont necessarily update positions